# Multithreading with _beginthread and CreateThread

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to write a Multithreading WIN32 Application in C++, but due to i get difficulties. 
One of the Window Procedure creates a Thread, which manages the output of this window. If this Window Procedure receives a message (from the other Window Procedures), it should transmit it to their Thread. At the beginning i worked with the _beginthread(...) function, what doesn't work. 
Then i tried it with the CreateThread(...) function, and it worked? What did i do wrong?
(My English isn't so good, i hope you understand my problem)

Code with CreateThread(...):

```
DWORD thHalloHandle; // global
HWND  hwndHallo;     // Hwnd of WndProc4
...
LRESULT APIENTRY WndProc4 (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 static PARAMS params ;

 switch (message)
 {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        params.hwnd = hwnd ;
        params.cyChar = HIWORD (GetDialogBaseUnits ()) ;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, thHallo, &params, 0, &thHalloHandle);
        return 0 ;
    }
...
    case WM_SPACE: {
        PostThreadMessage(thHalloHandle, WM_SPACE, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    }
...
}
```

Code with _beginthread(...):

```
...
case WM_CREATE: {
   params.hwnd = hwnd ;
   params.cyChar = HIWORD (GetDialogBaseUnits ()) ;
   thHalloHandle = (DWORD)_beginthread (thHallo, 0, &params) ;
   return 0;
}
...
case WM_SPACE: {
   PostThreadMessage(thHalloHandle, WM_SPACE, 0, 0);
   return 0;
}
...
```

thHallo for CreateThread:

```
DWORD WINAPI thHallo(void *pvoid)
{
    static TCHAR *szMessage[] = { TEXT(...), ...};
    // Some Declaration
    pparams = (PPARAMS) pvoid;
    while(!pparams->bKill)
    {
      MsgReturn = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
      hdc = GetDC(pparams->hwnd);
      if(MsgReturn)
      {
          switch(msg.message)
          {
             // case....
          }
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thHallo for _beginthread(...):

```
void thHallo(void *pvoid)
{
   ...
   // The Same like for CreateThread
   ...
   _endthread();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `CreateThread` puts the thread ID into `thHalloHandle`. The call to `_beginthread` puts the thread handle into `thHalloHandle`.

Now, the thread ID is not the same as the thread handle. When you call `PostThreadMessage` you do need to supply a thread ID. You only do that for the `CreateThread` variant which I believe explains the problem.

Your code lacks error checking. Had you checked for errors on the call to `PostThreadMessage` you would have found that `PostThreadMessage` returned `FALSE`. Had you then gone on to call `GetLastError` that would have returned `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`. I do urge you to include proper error checking.

In order to address this you must first be more clear on the difference between thread ID and thread handle. You should give `thHalloHandle` a different name: `thHalloThreadId` perhaps. If you wish to use `_beginthread` you will have to call `GetThreadId`, passing the thread handle, to obtain the thread ID. Alternatively, use `_beginthreadex` which yields the thread ID, or indeed `CreateThread`.

Comment: Is it not possible to make typcast the return value of _beginthread? And where should i call GetThreadId? In WndProc4 or thHallo?

Comment: @T.C. The point that you have to grasp is that `_beginthread` returns the **thread handle**. And the final parameter of `CreateThread` yields the **thread ID**. And they are completely different things. No amount of casting can turn an apple into an orange. You need a thread ID. Use `CreateThread` as you do. Or use `_beginthread` and call `GetThreadId` to obtain the thread ID. Or use `_beginthreadex`. Most of all, add some error checking.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you, David Heffernan you explained, what is the Problem in my implementation. The _beginthread() returns only a HANDLE to the Thread, so i had to get the TID with GetThreadId(HANDLE) to send with PostThreadMessage(..). CreateThread yields the ID in the address lpThreadId, so i get it "automatically"...

Comment: @T.C. Good. Now you should remember to accept what you deem to be the best answer. You got the same information from manuell and it's up to you to decide which answer you feel is better. Do also look back over your earlier questions please because I think that you can accept some answers there too. Thanks.

Comment: Is there generally and advantage of using _beginthread/CreateThread?

Comment: I think if I were developing with MSVC I would use `_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex` because that's a higher level interface. But nothing bad will happen if you chose `CreateThread` instead. On the other hand, since this is C++, you could use `std::thread`.

Comment: @T.C. There is a **significant** difference between `CreateThread` and `_beginthread[ex]`. The latter initializes the per-thread state the CRT needs - and performs cleanup when it terminates. If you run any code that executes CRT functionality on a thread, that thread **must** be created using `_beginthread[ex]`. Writing code that doesn't use the CRT is near impossible.

Comment: @IInspectable that was true, but is no longer the case

Comment: @David [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20901790/1889329) seems to come to the same conclusion. However, both are in conflict with the documentation for [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx). Do you happen to have a resource that explains when this changed, and how?

Comment: @IInspectable You have to ask Hans, but I trust him on this one. He is the expert around here on subjects like this. His point about the thread pool is quite right.

Answer (score 10):

The _beginthread/ex() function is proving to be radically difficult to eliminate.  It was necessary back in the previous century, VS6 was the last Visual Studio version that required it.  It was a band-aid to allow the CRT to allocate thread-local state for internal CRT variables.  Like the ones used for strtok() and gmtime(), CRT functions that maintain internal state.  That state must be stored separately for each thread so that the use of, say, strtok() in one thread doesn't screw up the use of strtok() in another thread.  It must be stored in thread-local state.  _beginthread/ex() ensures that this state is allocated and cleaned-up again.

That has been worked on, necessarily so when Windows 2000 introduced the thread-pool.  There is no possible way to get that internal CRT state initialized when your code gets called by a thread-pool thread.  Quite an effort btw, the hardest problem they had to solve was to ensure that the thread-local state is automatically getting cleaned-up again when the thread stops running.  Many a program has died on that going wrong, Apple's QuickTime is a particularly nasty source of these crashes.

So forget that _beginthread() ever existed, using CreateThread() is fine.

There's a serious problem with your use of PostThreadMessage().  You are used the wrong argument in your _beginthread() code which is why it didn't work.  But there are bigger problems with it.  The message that is posted can only ever be retrieved in your message loop.  Which works fine, until it is no longer your message loop that is dispatching messages.  That happens in many cases in a GUI app.  Simple examples are using MessageBox(), DialogBox() or the user resizing the window.  Modal code that works by Windows itself pumping the message loop.

A big problem is the message loop in that code knows beans about the messages you posted.  They just fall in the bit-bucket and disappear without trace.  The DispatchMessage() call inside that modal loop fails, the message you posted has a NULL window handle.

You **must** fix this by using PostMessage() instead.  Which requires a window handle.  You can use *any* window handle, the handle of your main window is a decent choice.  Better yet, you can create a dedicated window, one that just isn't visible, with its own WndProc() that just handles these inter-thread messages.  A very common choice.  DispatchMessage() can now no longer fail, solves your bug as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need a `TID` (Thread Identifier) to use `PostThreadMessage`.

`_beginthread` doesn't return a TID, it return a Thread Handle.

Solution is to use the [GetThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread (thHallo, 0, &params) ;
thHalloHandle = GetThreadId( hThread );
```

Better Code (see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx))

```
HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, thHallo, &params, 0, &thHalloHandle ) ;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed. I am sure OP will refactor code after reading our answers.